# iBatis Cachemodel for custom type handler

Tags: java, ibatis

I am trying to use cache model to cache the results returned from a procedure. But every time I hit the DB, It stores 'SERIALIZABLE NULL OBJECT' and the second time I hit the DB, it says cache miss and stores 'SERIALIZABLE NULL OBJECT'.
I am using iBatis 2 and calling a procedure.XML file looks like this:

```
<cacheModel id="TestCache" type="MEMORY">
<flushInterval seconds="600"/>
<property value="10" name="size"/>
<property name="reference-type" value="WEAK"/>
</cacheModel>

    <parameterMap id="getParameters" class="map">
        <parameter property="result" javaType="com.package.dto.SomeDTO" jdbcType="ORACLECURSOR" mode="OUT" typeHandler="com.dao.SomeResultHandler"/>
        <parameter property="userId" jdbcType="NUMERIC" mode="IN" />
        <parameter property = "applicationDate" jdbcType="DATE" mode="IN"/>
    </parameterMap>

     <procedure id="getUserDetails" parameterMap="getParameters" cacheModel="TestCache">
        {call pkcp_BPS.Get_User_Details (?,?,?)} 
    </procedure>
```

Comment: Having XML in the question would be more helpful for people who find this post later, bacase the screenshot can be deleted on the external site.

Comment: Sorry. I edited now.